# Minhag of avoiding showing pictures of dinosaurs to babies

Tags: kashrut-kosher, baby-infant

There is a minhag more common in Chassidic circles to refrain from showing pictures of non-kosher animals to babies. Does this apply to dinosaurs?

As far as I understand, this minhag does not apply to mythical creatures such as Pokemon. Presumably, then, this question boils down to whether the Torah views dinosaurs as mythical or not.

Comment: Or maybe it boils down to whether they are considered kosher or not? :)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30648

Comment: @RabbiKaii https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50293/is-it-acceptable-under-kashrut-to-eat-tyrannosauridae-meat

Comment: The real question is according to the view that the world was created with extinct dinosaurs in its geological history. Does the fact that they would have existed make them "real" retroactively?

Comment: Pokémon are fictional, not mythical...

Comment: Many of the marine species of dinosaurs are depicted as having fins and scales ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gift of a Teddy Bear to New Born Baby](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30648/gift-of-a-teddy-bear-to-new-born-baby)

Comment: @sabbahillel Bears are real animals.

Comment: @יהושעק and many of the land ones are depicted with feathers, so can we eat the herbivores?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I believe rabbi Peretz Flinstein ruled them kosher

Comment: @יהושעק I think Rav Obadiah ruled that cave painting to be a copyist mistake

Comment: Presumably then it is only a problem for those who believe that dinosaurs existed, which might be an interesting intersection with those who have that minhag.  Actually, is anything not kosher if it only existed before the Torah was given?  Conversely, maybe the opposite is true - could even the marine ones with fins and scales be considered kosher if they didn't exist when the Torah was given?

Comment: there is no end to the lunacy of minhag invention.

Answer (score -1):

I think the minhag you mention is a Chabad one, which doesn't allow for the use of any non-kosher species of animals as dolls or figurines. On the other hand, other communities have, for example, depictions of lions on the Aron Kodesh, and allow their children to play with teddy bears and the like.

Anyways, refraining from such figures would be merely a minhag, not a Halachah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150112/discussion-between-elonmusk-and-nissim-nanach).